# saving multiple input form arrays in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, input, foreach

I'm currently working on a project where I need to save multiple units in my MySQL database.

The html setup is as follows (this generated with a while loop from the database. The 0,1,2 is inserted by a php variable):

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="section[0][equal_columns]" value="<?php echo $item['equal_columns']; ?>" style="width: 25px;" />  Blokken even hoog
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="section[0][gutter]" value="<?php echo $item['gutter']; ?>" style="width: 25px;" />  Geen tussenruimte kolommen
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="section[0][full_width]" value="<?php echo $item['full_width']; ?>" style="width: 25px;" />  Sidewide grid
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="section[1][equal_columns]" value="<?php echo $item['equal_columns']; ?>" style="width: 25px;" />  Blokken even hoog
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="section[1][gutter]" value="<?php echo $item['gutter']; ?>" style="width: 25px;" />  Geen tussenruimte kolommen
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="section[1][full_width]" value="<?php echo $item['full_width']; ?>" style="width: 25px;" />  Sidewide grid
</p>
```

This info is submitted through a form which submits it on page. I have the following PHP/MySQL code to save this but sadly it's not working:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['save'])) {
    foreach($_POST['section'] as $index => $value) {
    $secquery .= "block_name = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $value['block_name'])."',
        parent_id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $uri[3])."',
        type_id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $value['type_id'])."',
        position = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $value['position'])."',
        background_image = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $value['background_image'])."',
        background_color = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $value['background_color'])."',
        padding_top = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $value['padding_top'])."',
        padding_bottom = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $value['padding_bottom'])."',
        margin_top = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $value['margin_top'])."',
        margin_bottom = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $value['margin_bottom'])."',
        gutter = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $value['gutter'])."',
        equal_columns = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $value['equal_columns'])."',
        ";
    }
    $save_sec_query = "INSERT INTO dtm_content_blocks SET ".$secquery." status = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['core']->mysqli, $_POST['status'])."'";
}
```

But the query foreach doesn't inputs the values from the input form.

My php also gives me the following error:

```
[2] Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/new_cms/controller/content/edit.php on line 119
```

I hope this is enough info for now. I could supply more if that is needed, but I can't get my head around this.

Comment: I always wonder why people bother to type out long lines of code when prepared statements are short and sweet.

Comment: are you sure that `$_POST['section']` contains something?

Comment: I've fixed the problem. Turned out the html wasn't in the form, but just outside of it.